# Reactjs + Nodejs + Nginx - Website is loading so long

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, debian, nginx-config

Well, i installed nginx on VPS (ovh.com)
then i put all files into /root/directory_site
then i setup nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.38.184.210;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://54.38.184.210:3000;
        proxy_buffering off;
 }
}
```

Now i got 2 problems

First one: After you go to http://54.38.184.210/
it's loading so long! Like 5-6 seconds before i see anything on website, i can only see the index title before, i think it might be the proxy_pass problem, but i don't how to fix it. It's impossible to load site like this that long, the server is fast, and my connection too!
(it's loading so long only when you try first time, so maybe it's something with cache?)

Second one:
i got errors like this in console:
[WDS] Disconnected!
What the hell is it? i never had it before on my local server!

What's the problem then? Im starting my website using "npm run dev"
you can try to access to the site, it's taking ages before it starting loading anything, where is the problem? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

WDS is webpack-dev-server, please never use development tools in production.

Why you got things fast locally? Because most heavy file, bundle.js, is loaded to browser from localhost, and you can load locally many Mb before it start to get long.

In proudction though you need to load bundle.js via internet, where speed is times slower. This is why good practice is to make your bundle.js under 2Mb and why in production build your bundle.js goes trhough minification process. Not only code, but assets, like images must be compressed, otherwise you going to load all this super long.

Also many packages has additional optimizations, when they built with environmental variable NODE_ENV=production. So please use minification tool, like uglifyjs, compress your assets and do not use any development tools/packages in production.

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.38.184.210;

    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://54.38.184.210:3000;
        #proxy_buffering off;
        root /root/site/dist/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;

 }
}

after i set the root folder to dist, i can see the site, it's loading very fast, but i don't know how to start the server now, can you tell me please?

Comment: Can you give more details on your installation? I mean do you have only client side, or client side served by express or separately client side and server?

Comment: @IvanCherviakov Read my conversation with him in my answer.

Comment: @Jechanka as chrispytoes said, you need to serve your website via express, then in prod you runnig express server with NODE_ENV=production on localhost, and then use nginx as reverse-proxy, so when you send request it get to nginx, nginx proxy it to express and express finally server your website.

Answer (score 0):

You are hosting the site directly off `webpack-dev-server`. This is bad and you should take this down right away. You need to make a production build and deploy it properly with the command `npm run build` if you are using `create-react-app`. Doing this will fix both issues.

Webpack Dev Server is for development purposes only and adds extra bloat to your app to make it easier to debug. This should not be used for a live server.

Comment: After i use npm run build, it created dist files, what should i do next to start the client/server, beacuse if i don't use the npm run dev, i got an errror
502 Bad Gateway
Im new with webpack, so please help me

Comment: @Jechanka That's perfect. The files in the `dist` folder is the entire website. Just serve that folder from a normal webserver like apache or nginx. If you don't know how to do that then that's a different question entirely.

Comment: when i set the root nginx to dist folder, it shows the website, but the backend is not working, i don't how to put it all together, can you please help me? i would like to create new topic but i have to wait 90 mins

```

Comment: @Jechanka Ah, you didn't mention that you had a backend. You will have to serve those files directly from whatever your back-end is, then route every request for a react page to `index.html`, and reverse-proxy to that backend server.

Comment: I don't get it, i got backend in node.js, each request im handling with express (app.use), which im sending from the client site, i thought i have just start the server using node

Comment: @Jechanka You can do `app.use(express.static('public'))`. Then make a folder called `public` in your application. Put the dist files in there, the files in the public folder will be served as a typical webroot. Then add another use statement at the very end of all your other routes so that it is caught last: `app.use('*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile('index.html')})`. This will catch any unfound routes and send them to your react application. Then just use nginx to reverse-proxy to your node.js app.

Comment: @Jechanka [Here is a tutorial to hopefully help more](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-serve-react-from-same-origin/) They are just calling the folder `build` here, but it can be called whatever you want. Scroll down to the Production part.

Comment: but i don't understand one thing, i got a components, im handling them with react route, where is the point to display any of it using backend? I don't understand it, on my local site, im starting the app using
npm run server
npm run client
and it display all, so why i can't do it like this using nginx?

Comment: Im trying dude, i spent almost few hours to handle the problem and i can't find the solution, i don't understand how can i handle static and dynamic content using nginx. I think i have something to do with the nginx config, but i already tried everything. Now when i set the location to the dist i got these errors: "POST 405 (Not Allowed)", i tried the express.static and app.use('*') but don't working

Comment: @Jechanka The only thing nginx should be doing is proxy-passing to your node.js app. You're overcomplicating it. Express should serve your API routes and your React application, nginx just proxies to nodejs and that's it. The code I showed you in my comment wasn't taking into consideration what you already have, since you didn't provide your backend code. Post another question about how to deploy a React application to production on Express, because now we're off-topic.